# Assertion failure in -[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:]

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Whenever i run this function i get assertion error, what should i do

```
   [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@device_model_no=%@&device_serial_no=%@&device_imei=%@&note=%@&disclaimer=%@&extra_note=%@&package_plan=%@&price=%@&duration=%@&device=%@&user_reg_id=%@&device_category=%@",KURL,txtModelNumber.text,txtSerialNo.text,txtIMEI.text,txtViewExtra.text,deviceDisclamer,additonalDetail.text,plan,price,duration,deviceName,userID,nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",link);

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager GET:link parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

        NSDictionary *returnedDealDict = responseObject ;
        NSArray *returnArray = [returnedDealDict objectForKey:@"result"];

        for(NSDictionary *dealDict in returnArray)
        {
            if ([dealDict objectForKey:@"success"])
            {
                ALERT_VIEW(@"Thanks1! Your information has been saved Successfully! We will contact you soon.")
            }
            else
            {
                ALERT_VIEW(@"Your information doesn t exist in our database, Please go back and enter your contact info again!")
            }
        }
        success();

        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];




    }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             ALERT_VIEW(@"Error occured while loading data.");
             NSLog(@"getBrandDevice Error");
             [MBPro

gressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
             }];
```

I get this error

```
** Assertion failure in -[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:], /Users/ios2/Desktop/untitled folder/PhablatFIx/PhablatFIx/MVC/Model/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m:277
    2014-09-25 10:33:26.733 PhablatFIx[721:90b]
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: URLString'
    *** First throw call stack:

Comment: What does the URL end up being?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to add this line of code in order to avoid invalid parameter url string

```
 NSString *encoded = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Working like a rocket!

Comment: Where to add this line? @noor

Answer (score 3):

> - (nullable NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc NS_DEPRECATED(10_0, 10_11, 2_0, 9_0, "Use
>     -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead, which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding, and which encodes for a
>     specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or
>     subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.");

@NullData answer work perfectly at this moment, but method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated so , you guys should consider to use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` method instead.

like this for swift

```
let path = myurlstring.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

or this for objc

```
path = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 3):

May url address is incorrect, there are spaces, wrong characters , etc. For example: 
[image]